# Why does Visual Studio 2010 ask me to update a solution created in 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm trying to open a VS 2010 solution on another computer, and VS is prompting me to update the solution. I don't understand why.

Here's the story.

I created a solution with Visual Studio 2010 on computer A, checked it into a Mercurial repository, and pushed it to the central server. Then I went on computer B, and pulled the repo. When I tried to open the solution, I got the update wizard.

Computer A has VS 2010 SP1, and computer B has both VS 2010 SP1 and VS 2012. Both computers have the required .NET Framework versions, and computer A does not have .NET 4.5.

Can someone explain why I need to update the solution from 2010 to 2010?

Comment: Well at a guess you've opened it in VS2012? Run up VS2010 on machine B, and then file open from the menu.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, I opened it with 2010.

Comment: Create dummy solution in 2010 on both machines and diff the sln and maybe the prj files. Mind you, if they are different (tools version attribute??). Not a clue how it could be or even if it could be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it wanted to update because it's an Excel 2007 addin, and I have Office 2010. Visual Studio by default requires you to upgrade Office projects to your current version.

The solution is to deselect Tools > Options > Office Tools > Project Upgrade > Always upgrade to an installed version of Office.